# How to display jsonresult data as a chart view and not an array in asp.net mvc using google charts (pie)

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization, google-pie-chart

I am trying to display a google pie chart based on a particular query but the result i get is:
[["Status","TotalProgress"],["Completed",1],["In-Progress",2],["To-Do",1]]
it should be:

[expected pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80iVG.png)
in my code the scenario is as follows:
a supervisor wants to view a selected students progress:
controller method(i used this tutorial but it does not include the "id" factor):
[link to tutorial i used](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Google-Charts-in-ASPNet-MVC-Google-Pie-Doughnut-Chart-example-with-database-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)

controller method:

```
 public JsonResult AjaxMilestoneStatus(string id)
    {

        string query = $"SELECT Status, COUNT(Progress) AS TotalProgress from Milestone  
       Where StudentNumber = '{id}' GROUP BY Status";
        // string query = "SELECT Status, COUNT(Progress) AS TotalProgress from 
       Milestone GROUP BY Status ";

        string constr = 
         ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

        List<object> chartData = new List<object>();
        chartData.Add(new object[]
                        {
                        "Status", "TotalProgress"
                        });
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        chartData.Add(new object[]
                        {
                        sdr["Status"], sdr["TotalProgress"]
                        });
                    }
                }

                con.Close();
            }
        }

        return Json(chartData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

then the view looks like this:

```
enter code here

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<h1></h1>

@*<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>*@
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
         $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
             url: "/CHART/AjaxMilestoneStatus",

            data: '{id: id}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                var data =  google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r);

                //Pie
                var options = {
                    title: 'My Progress'
                };
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart($("#chart")[0]);

                chart.draw(data,options);
            },
            failure: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);
            },
            error: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);
            }

        });
    }
   </script>

   <div id="chart" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

`

i had read somewhere that i should call the jsonresult method to a view in my controller if this is the way i should do it please assist me, i have really struggled, please help!
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

View

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                //my url is different than yours
                //url: "/CHART/AjaxMilestoneStatus",
                url: "/Home/AjaxMilestoneStatus",
                //took off parens in my data
                data: { id: $("#aHidden").val() },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r);
                    //Pie
                    var options = {
                        title: 'My Progress'
                    };
                    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart($("#chart")[0]);
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                },
                failure: function (r) {
                    alert(r.d);
                },
                error: function (r) {
                    alert(r.d);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <input type="hidden" id="aHidden" value="2" />
    <div id="chart" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
    public JsonResult AjaxMilestoneStatus(string id)  
    {
        //swapped {id} with {0}
        string query = String.Format(@"SELECT Status, COUNT(Progress) AS TotalProgress from Milestone Where StudentNumber = '{0}' GROUP BY Status",
                                        id);

        string constr =
         ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constring"].ConnectionString;

        List<object> chartData = new List<object>();
        chartData.Add(new object[]
                    {
                    "Status", "TotalProgress"
                    });
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        chartData.Add(new object[]
                    {
                    sdr["Status"], sdr["TotalProgress"]
                    });
                    }
                }

                con.Close();
            }
        }

        return Json(chartData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: hey thank you but unfortunately this is not working i am now getting a view with a "no data" text... do you have a action result method in the controller? and is the                    
   "[AHCCCS\KXBlau]"     before the [AHCCCS\KXBlau].Milestone important?

Comment: okay i finally got it to work the issue was the id, but i need to get the id from the controller not to manually put it, how could i do it

Comment: I show getting it from a field in the view and passing that value to the controller.  You can override this in the controller.  Please let me know how I can help.